# Define enum accessible from any submodule, in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, enums

I have an Android Project with many modules. I defined enum

```
enum Season {
    Summer, Fall, Winter, Spring
}
```

in main module's `build.gradle` but I cannot access it from any of the submodules' `build.gradle`. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it possible through one file containing said enum structure and "including" it in root *build.gradle*:

```
allprojects {
    apply from: new File(rootDir, 'path/to/file')
}
```

Content of the file has to be structured this way:

```
def enum SomethingEnum {
    FOO, BAR
}

ext {
    Something = SomethingEnum
}
```

After this two conditions are met, it is possible to write anywhere in submodules' *build.gradle* `Something.FOO`; and as usual for groovy, no autocomplete.